# How to display custom message on Aptible ssh login

Tags: docker, aptible

I want to display a custom message whenever anyone creates a SSH session on Apitble.

To do this, I have added a entrypoint script in Dockerfile to display the message.

```
echo "message"
exec "$@"
```

But this is causing `before_release` commands execution failure.

Apitble is passing chained commands, for ex: `command1 args && command2 args` to the docker.
Docker is executing `command1` and treating `args && command2 args` as it's arguments and throwing this error.

```
command1: error: unrecognized arguments: && command2 args
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not able to reproduced this issue with local containers. I don't know how Aptible passes arguments to container for execution but, talked to support and they provided two solutions.

1. Put commands inside a script, and call that one command alone from `before_release`.
2. Use `exec /bin/sh -c "$*"`, instead of `exec "$@"` in your `entrypoint.sh` script